# Fragment unintentionally behind other views

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a container build like this:

```
RelativeLayout container
--LinearLayout
  --TextView
--LinearLayout
  --Button
  --Button
```

And i am trying to add a Fragment "ListFragment" into the container showing ABOVE the two LinearLayouts with this:

```
ListFragment listfragment = new ListFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contianer,listfragment).commit();
```

The issue is: It doesnt. It only is displayed above the second LinearLayout, and the first LinearLayout is still visible ABOVE the Fragment.

Here are both xmls:

Container xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contianer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Button"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:background="#009688"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/vanisherView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/erklareung"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="40dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

The container is wrapped in another Layout, but i think, that doesnt really matter.

Here is the Fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:id ="@+id/viewer_layout">

    <com.woxthebox.draglistview.DragListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drag_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ive painted the Fragment Black, to see where it is shown, and where not

Thanks for answers and cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to add a `Fragment` to a container view that already contains other views.

Instead, place a `FrameLayout` wherever you want the `Fragment` to be placed and then add your `Fragment` to that instead of the parent container.

You can set the required attributes on the `FrameLayout` to ensure it is placed where you want it within your `RelativeLayout`.

**Example:**

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/container>"

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>

    <LinearLayout>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your layout into `FrameLayout`

```
FrameLayout
--RelativeLayout   //layout with your views
--FrameLayout      //container for your fragment
```